# What's the difference between generic and non-generic use of interfaces?

Tags: go, generics, interface

In the new [Type Parameters Design Draft](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md), you can now apply an interface constraint to a generic function:

```
func prettyPrint[T Stringer](s T) string {
    ...
}
```

But, this was already possible by using an interface parameter without generics:

```
func prettyPrint(s Stringer) string {
    ...
}
```

What's the difference between using the first and using the second?

Comment: "that's very particular about only having one way to do a thing" --- that's not true, and have never been true. You have chosen a bad example to ask though, try to implement a type safe `sync.Map` with and without generics - and implementation would be the answer to your question.

Answer (score 7):

I assume the question refers to the latest draft of the [Type Parameters proposal](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md#values-of-type-parameters-are-not-boxed), which [may end up in Go in 1.18](https://blog.golang.org/generics-proposal).

---

The first is parametric polymorphism. The compiler verifies that the constraint is satisfied, and then generates code that takes a statically-known type. Importantly, [it's not boxed](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/go2draft-type-parameters.md#values-of-type-parameters-are-not-boxed).

The second is runtime polymorphism. It takes a type that's unknown at compile time (the only thing known is that it implements the interface) and works on a [boxed interface pointer](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces).

Performance considerations aside, in this simple case you can use either approach. Generics really help with the more complicated cases where the [current tools don't work well](https://blog.golang.org/why-generics).

Comment: Another reason to use generics over interfaces is when the return type of a function is the same as a parameter - or when it's a collection-type (and then we get to _have fun_ with covariant/contravariance)